# When is it safe to leave out a const from a function's parametrization?

Tags: c++, constants, parameter-passing, function-signature

Many times I write C++ functions I seem to use many more `const` modifiers than other folks.

For example, I write Excel .xlsx files and I use LibXL library for this, and the [documentation](https://www.libxl.com/documentation.html) mentions a function like this:

```
bool writeNum(int row, int col, double value, Format* format = 0)
```

I happened to inherit this function and my signature looks like this:

```
bool XLAPIENTRY writeNum(const int row, const int col, const double value, IFormatT<wchar_t> * format = 0);
```

Note the `const int`s for the row and the column.

Question: is it safe to leave out `const` for `int`s? (It's obviuos that for pointers, leaving out const for pointers is dangerous, but doing something a local copy of an `int` is not that dangerous). Note that the original header containing writeNum function doesn't mention const-ing the `int`s, too. Why is here the `const` modifiers left out?

Comment: It's safe to leave out `const` for ints (and doubles)

Comment: See also [this discussion](/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters) which now would have been closed because of "asking for opinions".

Comment: Note that `const int* ptr` and `int* const ptr` are two different declarations. In the first the `int` is constant, in the second the pointer is constant. In the second case it's also safe to leave out the `const`, just as with ints.

Comment: Using `const` has several related purposes here, which are not clearly annotated separately in C++. 1) It is a contract with the caller. This is only important for references and pointers (with `const` before the `*`), not for non-pointer parameters by value. 2) The parameters act like local variables in the called function. Using `const` would actually be an implementation detail, which has leaked into the function signature. This is relevant for non-pointer value parameters and pointers with `*` before `const`. 3) The `const` can also be a performance hint for the optimizer.

Comment: In your case, 1) does not apply for the `int`s - they are value parameters. 3) The `int`s can be copied without effort, they are typically smaller than a 64-bit-pointer, so internally using a const reference (which would be a possible optimization for larger objects) would be slower. So only 2) remains, which is an implementation detail of your function. There were ideas (and proposals) to now treat the signature of const value parameters like non-const value parameters, but those will probably go nowhere to keep backwards compatibility.

Comment: @john  The same goes with `int const v`.  It's actually a specific rule in the standard that makes `const Type thing` and `Type const thing` equivalent - and that rule doesn't apply to your first sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **declaration** (as opposed to definition), the top-level<sup>1</sup> const on a parameter has no effect. Arguably, it's an implementation detail of the function, that shouldn't appear in the declaration (it adds clutter, yet doesn't provide any new information for the caller).

Note that `const int x` and `int *const x` are top-level const, while `const int *` and `const int &` are not, so the latter can't have its `const` removed.

In **definition**, you can include the `const` if it helps you as the implementer of the function (so you don't change the parameter accidentally).

---

<sup>1</sup> "Top-level const" means "actually const", as opposed to e.g. merely being a pointer to const. You can check this property with `std::is_const_v`.

E.g.:

- `std::is_const_v<const int> == true` (**const** integer)
- `std::is_const_v<const int *> == false` (**non-const** pointer to const integer)
- `std::is_const_v<int *const> == true` (**const** pointer to non-const integer)
- `std::is_const_v<const int **> == false` (**non-const** pointer to non-const pointer to const integer)
- `std::is_const_v<int *const *> == false` (**non-const** pointer to const pointer to non-const integer)
- `std::is_const_v<int **const> == true` (**const** pointer to non-const pointer to non-const integer)

Comment: Huh.

As far as I understand top-level const is a const pointer, while low level const is a constant value. 

1. Is it right?

2. If so, why "const in x" is a top-level stuff (if "x" means here the name of the parameter).

Comment: @GyulaSámuelKarli 1. Yes. 2. For non-pointer types, there's only one "level" of constness, so it can be considered top-level too. Or, for `int **x`, there are three possible places where `const` can be added (3 levels), and only one of them is "top-level" (the `int **const x` one).

Comment: @GyulaSámuelKarli In general, if `std::is_const_v` returns true, then it's top-level const. `std::is_const_v<const int>` is true.

Comment: A naive question, is "top-level" an obvious stuff for somebody in the C++ business? I think this should be added to the answer

Comment: @GyulaSámuelKarli I was hoping it's going to be obvious, but maybe not. I've added a short explanation.

Comment: That's cool, I really appreciate it. Most manuals about const stuff leave out these details and I now read Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ book and that doesn't go into such depth, too.